# pandas.io.sql: syntax error at or near "top"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, amazon-redshift

```
    sql = """SELECT * FROM "%s" where 1=1;""" % table_name

    df = sqlio.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

This snippet works fine. Now I want to modify the command such that I only extract let's say the first 100 rows. I tried modifying like this:

```
    sql = """SELECT * FROM "%s" where 1=1 top 100;""" % table_name
    df = sqlio.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

but it gives a syntax error near or at Top. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in SQL you can use `LIMIT` to limit the number of rows returned, i.e.

```
    sql = """SELECT * FROM "%s" where 1=1 limit 100;""" % table_name
    df = sqlio.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

The syntax for `TOP` is a bit different. See also [this W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).